# Where to create objects received by args?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, architecture, arguments, factory

I'm doing an assignment for a company and I would like to deliver a nice solution. I should create a shopping cart with special offers, where the products will be inputted by args.
I'm using a switch case to create this products, like:

```
public Product createByName(String productName) {
    switch (productName) {
        case "Soup": return new Soup();
        case "Bread": return new Bread();
        case "Milk" : return new Milk();
        case "Apple" : return new Apple();
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown product " + productName);
    }
}
```

my question is, is it better to call this createByName inside a loop in my Main, or pass the List args to a UI, that will pass it to a Controller, and create this objects inside the controller?

Thank you.

Comment: The second option would be better, but I suggest you use some design pattern for this , like `Factory pattern` or `Abstract factory` pattern, to create objects! Also creating objects one by one would be overhead for code !

Comment: Really thank you for your comment.
I will look into those patterns.
I'm sorry, what do you mean by creating objects one by one? Is this fixed by using those design patterns?

Comment: One by one means , the way you are creating will create more overhead! If you are using framework like `Spring` or `spring boot` , I suggest you use `@Autowired` on objects, this way you won't be creating objects everytime you call that method